# React.js infinitely add boxes and containers inside of any other containers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, containers, frontend, web-frontend

I'm a beginner at React and want to know how to implement this functionality:
At the beginning there is one **main** container with "Add" label. When I hover this label, two buttons appear: box and container. - that is what I have done. And what I should implement: 
1. Each button should add corresponding item (box or container with label) to the parent container.
2. "Container" button should add container (with Add label) inside the parent container, so we can add a box or container inside of any other container which are located in the **main** container.
3. "Box" button should add box to the container where click was fired.
Question: So how do I create such buttons to manipulate components (and what components should I use) and how I should organize components in App.js?
I would be so happy if someone could help!

Comment: Did you try adding this functionality on your own? If yes, even if your code isn't working, post it, please?

Comment: I didn't, because I don't get what components should I use and how to organize them (inside which parent components they need to be located)